# Trigger event not working inside Ajax Magnific popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magnific-popup

I'm loading a page inside a magnific popup vie ajax:

```
$("#operator").magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a.edit',
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    closeBtnInside: true,
    removalDelay: 300,
    closeOnContentClick: false,
    type: 'ajax',
    ajax: {
        settings: {
            url: 'index.php?p=staff/operators',
        }
    },
    callbacks: {
        elementParse: function() {
            this.st.ajax.settings.data = {
                operator_id: this.st.el.attr('data-id')
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Inside the modal window I want to fire a trigger event on a input type="file":

```
$('input[name^=\'upload\']').on('change', function() {
    $('#form-upload').remove();
    $('#staff').prepend('<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-upload" style="display: none;"><input type="file" name="file" /></form>');

    $('#form-upload input[name=\'file\']').trigger('click');

    if ($('#form-upload input[name=\'file\']').val() != '') {

        $.ajax({
            /* upload file code */
        });
        ecc...
    });
```

But it doesn't trigger. Also, all other trigger events aren't working inside the magnific popup.

So how can I get trigger events working inside the magnific popup?

Comment: Add the event handlers in the callback for the popup, after the elements actually exists, or use delegated event handlers

Comment: @adeneo the hidden form is created inside the MP, so how to attack a callback to an element which doesn't already exist?

Comment: @Someone33 You can attach them as I explain in my answer. But, according to you comment to my answer, you have a very different problem. You shpuld improve your question by giving extra information. If not, every answer will be a shot in the dark

Comment: @JotaBe No event is triggered. I checked it with: `$('#form-upload input[name=\'file\']').on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.originalEvent === undefined) alert ('triggered by code');})`

Comment: Don't check it with $('#form-upload'). Do check it with the syntax in my answer: $('body'). etc. The difference is very important!!

Answer (score 0):

As the HTML is loaded by ajax, by the tiem you try to attach the event, the element is not available, so nothing is attached.

You have to change you '.on()' call, so that it selects an element which contains the popup element, and use a filter so that only the change by the `name=upload` is handled. Something like this:

```
$('body').on('change','input[name^=\'upload\']', function() { ...
```

By the way, to avoid escaping characters in javascript, you can exchange single and double quotes. So you can simply use this filter:

```
'input[name^="upload"]'
```

or

```
"input[name^='upload']"
```

(Please, do test them. I think only the first one is valid).

Comment: The problem is not the "change" event, which is already working. The hidden for is successfully added, but then the button won't trigger because the magnific popup has some sort of stop propagation or similar. If you try to trigger any other event inside a magnific popup ot won't fire until the modal window isn't closed again, but then it's obviously too late :-)